# Combine these into one function - that does the same thing - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am looking to take the following:

```
    $('.formWrapper').on('change', 'select', function(){
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        console.log(data);
    });

    $('.formWrapper').on('change', 'input', function(){
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
```

And convert it into one function where it watches both `input` and `select`... What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.formWrapper').on('change', 'select , input', function(){
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I didnt know you could do the 'attr, attr, ...'

Comment: @TheWebs: The comma lets you combine multiple selectors into one: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: you can add them comma separated,all your selectors